# How to display a message to the user when the website is loaded by clicking the hyperlink provided in email is clicked

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, html, django

Hi I have the code below:

**view.py**

```
        try:
            url = "associateid="+assoc_id+"&quarter="+quarter+"&manager="+mgr_id
            #print(url)
            encoded=base64.b64encode(bytes(str(url),'utf-8'))
            urle = 'http://localhost:8000/index/file?enc_url='+encoded.decode("utf-8")
            #print(urle)
            vals = {'emailapproved':str(urle)}
            response_dict["data"].append(vals) 
        except Exception as e:
            print(str(e))
```

**index.html**

```
<table border='0' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='2'>
<tr><td ><a href="{{emailapproved}}" target="blank" id="accessLink"> Click here To launch the webpage</a><font color='#0d94d2'></font></td></tr></table>
```

How to display a message when the user clicks on the link which is provided in the email and once the website launches.

Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: You have to handle the message display in the target URL. Like if you have `a.html` and `b.html`, your click is from `a -> b`, then write some query in `b.html`. You can also pass url query params to show messages also.

Comment: You should tell when to show the message: in current page before redirect to the new url, or in the new page after redirected?

Comment: You can make a simple ajax call to your view and get the message in your response.

Comment: @Waket Zheng I want the message in the new page

Answer (score 0):

You can use Django messages framework ([docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/messages/)). Write following code in the view which is called when user click on link in your email.

```
from django.contrib import messages
messages.add_message(request, messages.INFO, 'Hello world.')
```

Write following code in your base template

```
{% if messages %}
<ul class="messages">
    {% for message in messages %}
    <li{% if message.tags %} class="{{ message.tags }}"{% endif %}>{{ message }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
{% endif %}
```

When message will be added in your request, when user will open any page in django, he will see that message.

Answer (score 0):

A similar example which will show message if success to send sms to the phone inputted:

```
{% extends "admin/base_site.html" %}
{% load i18n admin_urls admin_list %}
{% block title %}This is Title{% endblock %}
{% block branding %}
<h1 id="site-name">My Site Name</h1>
{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
    <form method="post">{% csrf_token %}
      <!-- there is a button whoes element id is `sendSms` in the form -->
      <!-- click it will make a ajax request, then alert a message box to show the result -->
      {{ form.as_p }}
      <input type="submit" value="submit">
    </form>
  <script>
    var smsBtn = document.getElementById('sendSms');
    smsBtn.onclick = function() {
      var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
      xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4){
          if(xmlhttp.status==200||xmlhttp.status==201){
            document.getElementById("sendSms").disabled=true;
            alert('success to send sms!')
          }else{
            alert('fail!')
          }
        }
      }
      xmlhttp.open('POST', '/v1/vcode/send/', true);
      var phone=document.getElementById('id_phone').value;
      xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/json");
      xmlhttp.send(JSON.stringify({ phone }));
    }
  </script>
{% endblock %}
```